# How do I fix the Steam Overlay in Payday 2?

Tags: technical-issues, payday-2

For some reason, the Steam Overlay doesn't seem to work, despite the fact that it is enabled. How can I make the Steam Overlay work so I don't have to tab out to answer Steam messages anymore?

Answer (score 1):

According to multiple sources, running Payday 2 in compatibility mode for Windows 98 / ME (yes you read that correctly) will fix this issue. So I tried, and, sure enough, my Steam Overlay works.

To do this, find the exe file for Payday 2 (mine was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2\`), right click, and hit "Properties". From there, go to the "Compatibility" tab, check the box next to "Run this program in compatibility mode for:", and select "Windows 98 / ME".

[image: The Properties Window]

This probably sounds like the weirdest thing ever, but, sure enough, it works.

Comment: Are you running on Win8 by any chance?

Comment: @Fluttershy Win7.

Comment: If you're using Win8 and enable compatibility mode, you also have a chance to get huge amounts of lag.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have conflicting overlays enabled! I've noticed my Steam Overlay was always gone if Mumble's was enabled and vice versa.

Comment: The Steam Overlay was not working at all, regardless of whether or not Mumble was running at all.

Comment: @Unionhawk This was the case for me, maybe it's the same for someone else. Also, it's not just Mumble, some other overlays do the same. Mumble was just an example.